# Making a list that returns the result with any index, despite "list out of range error"

Tags: python

I'm looking for some simple nifty solution that prevention "list out of range error" for list at all

For example

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
l[3]  # 1, first element of the list
l[-4]  # 3, last element of the list
```

I think that must be some class. I was very surprised when not found it in standard modules. For itertools there a cycle, but it is not quite that I want

Comment: Your last edit makes what you mean, that was not completely explicit but could be guessed, almost impossible to understand...

Comment: There is no way, the `list` API is not designed for this. You have to write the code to handle this yourself

Comment: Yes, I sorry, I was wrong when I wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions

1) use a proxy function to access the list

```
def my_getitem(l, key):
    return l[key % len(l)]


l = [1, 2, 3]
my_getitem(l, 3)  # 1
```

2) use a custom subclass of list which overloads subscript operator

```py
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return super().__getitem__(key % len(self))


l = MyList([1, 2, 3])
l[3]  # 1
```

the above two code snippets effectively translates your cyclic indexes into ordinary list indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that does it for you

```
>>> def my_index(l, idx):
...     return l[idx % len(l)] if l else None
... 
>>> my_index(l,-4)
3
>>> my_index(l,3)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

- You could dynamically call it with `yourlist[INDEX % (len(yourlist))]`
- Or you could create a function that does just the thing.

```
def fun(yourlist, INDEX):
        return yourlist[ INDEX % (len(yourlist)) ]
```